# Saving Silverlight source files takes ages

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

After hitting Save button and saving the files in a Silverlight project takes almost a minute. Same thing happens after exiting debugging mode and this happens only with Silverlight projects.

Anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: I haven't seen anything similar.  Can you include the version/edition of Visual Studio you are using?

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2010 10.0.40219.1 and SP1 installed.

Comment: Time to repave your development machine. Pretty standard practice.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a clean installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just shots in the dark but....

Disable addons (ReSharper, DevExpress, etc..)

Checkout C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
(more info at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/347228/large-numbers-of-websitecache-files-slowing-visual-studio-2005-and-windows-performance)

Remove projects from the solution

Disable Intellisense.

Comment: Standard Silverlight projects don't seem to have this problem but all the WCF RIA services applications have this issue. After saving, compiling and exiting debugging mode I have to wait almost 30 seconds and the Visual Studio eats up the CPU. This is a clean install.